# How do I make the system-wide proxy settings bypass the proxy for local addresses?

Tags: networking

I set global proxy settings via

```
System Settings>Network>Network proxy
```

I set the Socks host. All apps, including the command line apps successfully picked it up. But its a problem with Mercurial, which has trouble finding a PC on the same network. How do I set the system proxy settings to exempt local addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the configuration window you mentioned there is a tab like "ignored Computers" (In my german ubuntu it is: "Ignorierte Rechner"). There you can setup rules for connections which do not need to be forwarded to the proxy. You could e.g. add:

```
192.168.*.*
```

to this list, depending on which room is "local" for you.

edit: I mean this settings page:

[image]

Comment: Hmm I see only host-address pairs for HTTP Proxy,HTTPS Proxy,FTP Proxy and SOCKS host, with an "Apply system wide". Greetings from India, Jesvin :-)

Comment: I added a picture of the dialog box I meant...